# In AWS Lambda using Node, can't get Express to work with aws-serverless-express

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Below is my sample code that is not working.  No matter what I set up, I can't get Express to render my ejs page.

Note: I have an API Gateway in front of the Lambda.   That will only let in the traffic I want.  Everything that hits my Lambda should have the express page rendered.   While not in the code I am showing below, once working, I will do some validation and lookups before using express to show the page.

index.js

```
"use strict";

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./displayRouter.js');
const serverDisplay = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app.router)

exports.handler = async  (event, context, callback) =>{

    try
    {
        console.log("testing");
        app.setValues("setting values called correctly");
        console.log("before awsserverless")
        await awsServerlessExpress.proxy(serverDisplay, event, context);
        console.log("after call to awsserverless");
    }catch(e){
        console.log("ALERT:   500 error " + e); 
    }
}
```

displayRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express();

router.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const setValues = async (testValueIn) => 
{
    console.log("setting Values IN ROUTER");
    console.log("value sent i:  " + testValueIn);
}


router.set('views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

router.all('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('inside function before diaplying page');
    res.render("emailTestPage",{ });
  });


module.exports = {router, setValues};
```

Note, I call setValues to prove that I am reaching the page correctly. You can see that in the output below.  But when I call router.all, it is never actually hit.   I have tried router.use('/'...., router.get('/'..., router.post('/', ...    None of them are every hit.

Output in Lamda log:

```
2022-03-12T17:41:41.567-05:00   2022-03-12T22:41:41.549Z ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7 INFO testing

2022-03-12T17:41:41.568-05:00   2022-03-12T22:41:41.567Z ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7 INFO setting VALUES IN ROUTER

2022-03-12T17:41:41.568-05:00   2022-03-12T22:41:41.568Z ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7 INFO value sent i: setting values called correctly

2022-03-12T17:41:41.568-05:00   2022-03-12T22:41:41.568Z ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7 INFO before awsserverless

2022-03-12T17:41:41.607-05:00   2022-03-12T22:41:41.570Z ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7 INFO after call to awsserverless

2022-03-12T17:41:41.669-05:00   END RequestId: ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7

2022-03-12T17:41:41.669-05:00   REPORT RequestId: ggea5c27-4955-42c0-baf9-501e3f071bc7 Duration: 160.20 ms Billed Duration: 161 ms Memory Size:
```

EDIT********
I have dumbed this down to one page.   It is still not working.

```
"use strict";

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log('inside app');
    res.render("testPage",{ });
});


exports.handler = async  (event, context, callback) =>{

    try
    {
        console.log("CREATING SERVER");
        let server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);        
        await awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
        console.log("after call to awsserverless");
    }catch(e){
        console.log("ALERT:   500 error " + e); 
    }
}
```

and here is the output

```
2022-03-14T13:29:02.142-04:00   2022-03-14T17:29:02.124Z ddde0b20-2700-470a-bcff-af81aec74f61 INFO CREATING SERVER

2022-03-14T13:29:02.223-04:00   2022-03-14T17:29:02.185Z ddde0b20-2700-470a-bcff-af81aec74f61 INFO after call to awsserverless

2022-03-14T13:29:02.286-04:00   END RequestId: ddde0b20-2700-470a-bcff-af81aec74f61

2022-03-14T13:29:02.286-04:00   REPORT RequestId: ddde0b20-2700-470a-bcff-af81aec74f61 Duration: 191.47 ms Billed Duration: 192 ms Memory Size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.   I wasted so much time on such a simple mistake.   I needed to add "return" to the awsServerlessExpress.proxy line.

```
return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context,'PROMISE').promise;
```